DCC Error E2597 ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib for architecture arm64 linking Delphi 12.1 app SDK 17
with Delphi 12.1 SDK 17 (mandatory fo new AppStore apps), xcode 15.0.1 on a armMac OS 14.5,
first i had this linker error
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FC:\Users\franz\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS17.0.sdk\System\Library\PrivateFrameworks'
  ld: file not found: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVFCapture.framework/AVFCapture for architecture arm64

Having noticed that my app worked well in simulator mode, i manually copied the PrivateFramework Directory under the
C:\Users\franz\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS17.0.sdk

directory, after that i received another linker error
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib for architecture arm64

With the same delphi version and the same apple machine configuration, yesturday I was able to compile and link the same app, but the Apple Store refuses new apps using the 16x framework
Prior to search help, I cleared all cache and manually removed directoris under my local windows machine. I really don't know how to go on, please helm me.
thank you.

I have resolved manually updating the xCode in the target apple machine at the 17.5 version and all works well.
